# Javascript image slideshow iteration - why is the last image first

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a small slideshow. The slideshow consists of six images each with their own caption. There is also one static general caption.

The code below works but it shows the last image first, then skips the first image and iterates through the rest. After the first round everything is in order, so why is this happening please?

**CSS**

```
.imwrap {
    max-width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    font-family: Roboto;
}

.imgsx {
    position: absolute;
    transition: opacity 1.5s ease-in;
    max-width: 99%;
    border-radius: 13px;
}

.text {
    color: white;
    font-weight: bolder;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 8px 12px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 65%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%);
    text-align: center;
    transition: opacity 1.5s ease-in;
    width: fit-content;
    z-index: 2000;
    opacity: 0;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}

.numbertext {
    color: blue;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 8px 12px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
    border-top-right-radius: 8px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
    z-index: 100;
}

.imgsx+.imgsx {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="imwrap">
  <div class="numbertext">with kind permission from picturesofengland.com</div>  
  <img class="imgsx" src="./trip/railway.webp" alt="Railway">
  <div class="text">Swanage preserved railway - by Jack Rickard &copy;</div>
  <img class="imgsx" src="./trip/boats.webp" alt="Boats">
  <div class="text">Swanage - by Jenny Fairbrother &copy;</div>
  <img class="imgsx" src="./trip/night.webp" alt="Night time">
  <div class="text">Night time on the beach - by Stephen Williams &copy;</div>
  
  <img class="imgsx" src="./trip/training.webp" alt="Training ship">
  <div class="text">Training in Swanage Harbour &copy;</div>
  <img class="imgsx" src="./trip/buffet.webp" alt="Buffet car">
  <div class="text">Buffet Car, Swanage Station - Jenny Fairbrother &copy;</div>
  <img class="imgsx" src="./trip/sunny.webp" alt="Sunny evening">
  <div class="text" style="opacity:1">A Sunny evening in Swanage - by Jill Giles &copy;</div>
</div>
```

javascript

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script>
var current = 0,
  slides = document.getElementsByClassName("imgsx");
  caps = document.getElementsByClassName("text");
setInterval(function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        slides[i].style.opacity = 0;
        caps[i].style.opacity = 0;
    }
    current = (current != slides.length - 1) ? current + 1 : 0;
    slides[current].style.opacity = 1;
    caps[current].style.opacity = 1;
}, 5000);
</script>
```

Edit

Codepen example
https://codepen.io/dcsimp/pen/yLvvdwb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

follow the option of @Yaver Javid, you can use css animation

but I found the reason why you start with the last image

It places all the image with `opacity: 1`, and `position: abusolute` to place them on the same postion of outer element, like put paper on table, the last one will show and others will hide by it.

the solution is at the beginning setting all the image with `opacity: 0`, but cause you use `setTimeout` function, the first picture will appear in 5 seconds when page on load, you can set the first picture and text with `opacity: 1`

my edit is [here](https://codepen.io/xubeiyan/pen/ZErrgWr)

Answer (score 0):

Use css animations.

Make a div, then using css animations to change its background image every 5000ms.
And you can do the same for text. It will be much faster.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I will have to google css animations